# Force redraw Fragment inside FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmentstatepageradapter

My App works like a catalog I use Grids to show objects and people can select if they want that item.

So I'm populating a Grid Fragment with images, some of this fragments are static (number of images don't change) others are suppose to update when you add something new (Wanted items). The images are clickable to let you change the data of the correspondent object.

Those fragments are part of a FragmentStatePagerAdapter and I'm not capable of updating the dynamic ones, I have tried so many solutions and until now I've been only capable of making the fragment redraw itself when the screen rotates and that works fine.

In my MainActivity I have a method that checks if the data changes and when it does it asks the correspondent fragment to update his View.

```
private void updateFragments() {
    mData = ((Database) getApplication()).data;
    int[][] wanted = mData.getWanted();

    mAdapter.startUpdate(mViewPager);

    GridFragment f;
    if (!Arrays.deepEquals(mWanted, wanted)) {// mWanted.length != wantedT.length) {

        f = (GridFragment) mAdapter.getFragment(ArrayImages.NumberOfSeries);

        if (f != null)
            f.updateData(wanted);
    }

    mWanted = wanted;

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In my GridFragment I try to update the view with this method:

```
public void updateData(int[][] d) {
    data = d;

    if (this.getView() != null) {
        GridView gridView = (GridView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        if (data != null)
        if (data.length > 0) {
            customAdapter = new CustomImageAdapter(this.getActivity(), data);

            gridView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FullImageActivity.class);

                    // Passing array index
                    i.putExtra("pos", position);
                    if (series == ArrayImages.NumberOfSeries + 1)
                        i.putExtra("title", "Wanted");

                    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                    mBundle.putSerializable("data", new Integer2D(data));
                    i.putExtras(mBundle);

                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            //Clears the GridView
            gridView.setAdapter(null);
        }
    }

    notifyDataChanged();
}
```

My ViewPagerAdapter is looking like this:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
   private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
   private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
   private SparseArray<Fragment> map;
   //
   ....
   //

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
            return newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    public final Fragment newInstance(int series) {
        Fragment f = new GridFragment();

        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(3);
        bdl.putInt("SERIES", series);

        //Wanted grid
        if(series == ArrayImages.NumberOfSeries+1){
           DBHelper data = ((Database) context.getApplicationContext()).data;
           bdl.putSerializable("DATA", data.getWanted());
           data.close();
        }

        f.setArguments(bdl);

        return f;
    }

   @Override
   public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        if (obj instanceof Fragment) {
            // record the fragment tag here.
            Fragment f = (Fragment) obj;
            String tag = f.getTag();
            mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
        }

        return obj;
   }

    public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
       String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);

       if (tag == null)
          return null;

       return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }

    //Redraw on screen rotation
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Since the number of images will change and the images it self, how can I force to redraw the fragment or at least update the grid, when coming back to MainActivity?

Comment: Use onResume() in your MainActivity class to refresh your previous fragment

Comment: Thank you for the answer but where exactly should I use onResume()?
I'm trying to call it after changing the data, but it seems to get stuck in a loop of onResume().